# To create a big web app using django, what all things I should learn?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, backend

I am an intermediate django developer and I would like to more deeper concepts of django that would help me optimize queries, add mode functionalities to the app(I am a back end dev btw).

I know basics of django like model designing, views, drf etc..I need more in-depth knowledge

Comment: Some referecences:
https://github.com/HHHMHA/django-roadmap
https://gist.github.com/shahwan42/279f6ec17dfc91ec9c6f778ae2877b2d

Comment: Even more references: https://learndjango.com/tutorials/how-learn-django and https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/roadmap-learn-django-yasser-albarbary